# How to query all Korean words start with an initial character

Tags: android, sqlite

It is easy to query all the words start with an initial character in English, for example to query all the words start with "a", we execute this query:

```
SELECT * FROM table WHERE word LIKE 'a%';
```

We can get results like "an", "at", "after"....

But it is not the same in Korean, because a Korean word is considered as a single Unicode character,
so this query:

```
SELECT * FROM table WHERE word LIKE 'ㄱ%';
```

will not return words like "가", "고", "간"... (The results may like "ㄱ자", "ㄱ견"...)

So what I should do to get the result as I expect? (i.e. I will get words like "가", "고", "간"... when I want to query the word start with "ㄱ")

Thank you very much!

Answer (score 0):

Your problem here is one of unicode format and Korean's unique behavior of combining consonants and vowels to create a new character.  You can either store these new characters as individual glyphs, or as combined glyphs.  If you want to search like this, you need to store them as individual glyphs.  That means taking every incoming string that will be stored in the db and processing them before inserting them, breaking up compound glyphs into its components.  And if you have an existing db, you'd have to do that to the existing data as well.

The other route is to make a list of every possible combination of glyphs with that character with a complex expression in unicode, and search for all of them with a massive set of ORs.

Either way is a pain in the neck.  Asian languages can be a real problem for programmers, they all seem to have little things like that which make them difficult to process.